# I don't really understand this proof for alons "Nullstellensatz"

Tags: complex-analysis

[image: Theorem]
[image: Proof]

I didn't really understand the proof in the image. How do I choose the $h_i$ and why isn't $\widetilde{f}=f$?
I thought that is the case because the sum is exactly $x_i^t+1$ and so the replacement shouldn't change anything?
Would be very thankful if someone could help me!

Comment: there is? there are 2 images. the first one is the theorem and the second one the proof

Comment: My bad. I didn't see there were two hyperlinks

Comment: In general you shouldn't use pictures here. Try to use MathJax to format your mathematics, e.g. $g_i(x_i)=\prod_{s\in S_i}(x_i-s)$ as `$g_i(x_i)=\prod_{s\in S_i}(x_i-s)$`